# Ignore playlists for YouTube API V3

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a C# application I wrote that loops thru certain youtubers and retrieves video information from them.  All I care about is the videos themselves.  I recently ran into a problem where someone either created or updated a playlist and now it's erroring out because it's pulling that in as well.  Is there a way anyone knows to skip playlists when querying YouTube?  This is how I pull a list of videos for a particular youtuber today.

```
YouTubeService yt = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = YTubeAPIKey });
var searchListRequest = yt.Search.List("snippet");
searchListRequest.MaxResults = YTubeDownloadsPerUser;
searchListRequest.Order = SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Date;  // grab and order by newest to oldest
searchListRequest.ChannelId = youtubers;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official doc of the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint, if you'll include within the endpoint invoking request parameters the following one set appropriately, then you'll obtain only items corresponding to videos:

> [**`type`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) (string)
> The `type` parameter restricts a search query to only retrieve a particular type of resource. The value is a comma-separated list of resource types. The default value is `video,channel,playlist`.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - `channel`
> - `playlist`
> - `video`

Consequently, just add the following line to your code for the API to provide you with resources pertaining only to videos:

```
searchListRequest.Type = "video";
```

Also note that having set the request parameter `channelId` implies that `Search.list` will return a limited number of items (the emphasis below is mine):

> [**`channelId`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) (string)
> The `channelId` parameter indicates that the API response should only contain resources created by the channel.
>
> **Note:** Search results are constrained to a *maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the `channelId` parameter* and sets the [`type`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) parameter value to `video`, but it does not also set one of the [`forContentOwner`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forContentOwner), [`forDeveloper`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forDeveloper), or [`forMine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forMine) filters.

Comment: Thanks that was the ticket.  I found that shortly after posting but just got around to testing it.